# Selenium Hub Pause Data Stream

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-grid

I'm looking for a way to pause the data stream of a selenium hub.  The idea is to wait till the hub has finished processing a test/batch, put it on hold, send a kill command to node, on headless VM to restart, upon reconnect allow data stream to continue.  The idea is to allow the nodes/vm's to restart and refresh, potentially avoiding hangups and connection timeouts.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of pausing the data stream, you can create a java class that implements [TestSessionListener](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/server/src/org/openqa/grid/internal/listeners/TestSessionListener.java). This interface has the methods which can tell you when a test is starting and ending. You can write your custom code to restart the machines after each test or based on some other logic.

You can refer to [Selenium Grid Extras](https://github.com/groupon/Selenium-Grid-Extras) project which uses this.
For a much more simple example on creating a grid plugin refer the [Grid Plugin Tutorial](https://github.com/freynaud/grid-plugin-tutorial)